# number of rows executed in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please im launching a query on my postgresql table. The size of the table is 60GO, It tooks more than 2 hours and i want to see the number of rows that was executed, or simply the percentage of executed table.

Thank you in advance,

Tom.

Comment: `number of rows that was executed` ... what does this mean?  Why can't you just check the size of the result set?

Comment: In the same table, i mean i have a column x and i want to update x to have value(x) +1. If i have table with 4000 rows. I want to see the number of rows that was changed . For example 1000 rows was changed, and 3000 not. Hope that im clear :)

Comment: When you use the command line tool it will print the rows altered to the console. If you are using a programming language there will be a function you can call. If you tell us what tool or programming language you are using we can give more details

Comment: I think OP want's something like a progress indicator

Comment: Can you at least show us the query?